# Edit htaccess with php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi guys its possible and if yes how i can do this

on my htaccess on first line i have

```
DirectoryIndex home.php index.php
```

then

```
RewriteEngine On etc.....
```

so based on a option on my code i want to do

```
if (option=1) {
  // on htaccess write DirectoryIndex home.php index.php #first line
} else (option=2) {
  // on htaccess remove DirectoryIndex home.php index.php
}
```

also i dont know if this is safe

thanks for any help

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking. The `.htaccess` is read before PHP interprets your file. If your question is, can I change the file **for subsequent requests** using PHP, the answer is yes (using `fopen()` and `fwrite()` for example) but if it's for the current request, the answer is no.

Comment: If you ask that way you'll only get scaremongering answers. The safety of such an approach (and safety pertains to reliability more than to security) squarely depends on how exactly the file updating is implemented. Exchaning one line and a bit of file locking isn't difficult however.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's [filesystem functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) and edit it just like any other file.

However, it will only affect requests after the current one, not the one that makes the change. If this matters, have PHP do the same thing as the new `.htaccess` would.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you're trying to rewrite URLs dynamically, if so, there is another approach you can take.

Forward every request to rewrite.php?req=request (through one simple rewrite in the .htaccess)
`RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ rewrite.php?req=$1`

This would then e.g. rewrite home.php to rewrite.php?req=home.php

Now you can access the relevant request you want, in this case `home.php`, you could then act on this based on your settings. e.g.

```
<?php
$req = $_POST['req']; // need to sanitize this obv

if($option1) {
    // do something
} else if ($option2) {
    // something else
}
?>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: this is not about url rewrite - i m working on webradio website and this have a player and the main website so they usign 2 frames home.php (call the player.html frame and index.php frame with main site) so what i want is if the user want to use the website with the frames write on htacess DirectoryIndex home.php index.php if not remove DirectoryIndex home.php index.php frm htaccess

Comment: If by user you mean the visitors, then this isn't going to work, as .htaccess is a system change, and as such would affect all the users rather than just the one, however, the solution for this can be much simpler, what you'd do save a cookie/session of which one the user wants, if the user wants frames, you include home.php at the top of index.php and then exit, otherwise you just let index.php do what it wants.